# Tensorflow KeyError for creating train.record for model

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm current facing this error when creating a train.record file for my. I'm following a guide from [Medium](https://medium.com/swlh/tensorflow-2-object-detection-api-with-google-colab-b2af171e81cc)

Previously I had no issue but today I have this error

```
/content/gdrive/MyDrive/TensorFlow/scripts/preprocessing
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "generate_tfrecord.py", line 168, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 300, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "generate_tfrecord.py", line 158, in main
    tf_example = create_tf_example(group, path)
  File "generate_tfrecord.py", line 132, in create_tf_example
    classes.append(class_text_to_int(row['class']))
  File "generate_tfrecord.py", line 101, in class_text_to_int
    return label_map_dict[row_label]
KeyError: '\\'
Successfully created the TFRecord file: /content/gdrive/MyDrive/TensorFlow/workspace/training_demo/annotations/test.record
```

I suspect the problem might be with one of the annotation .xml file in my train image folder causing the issue but I can't seem to find any other sources to confirm. Can someone please enlighten me?

Edit: Here is the [generate_tfrecord.py](https://github.com/sglvladi/TensorFlowObjectDetectionTutorial/blob/master/docs/source/scripts/generate_tfrecord.py) for reference if required. Thank you

Comment: Is your issue resolved now? Else, can you share your annotation file and Colab file to replicate your issue. Thanks!